# Regex php, replace ul li by div

Tags: php, regex, html-lists

I have this list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="myclass">blablabla 1</li>
    <li class="myclass">blablabla 2</li>
    <li class="myclass">blablabla 3</li>
</ul>
```

And I want, with a regex, this:

```
<div class="newClass">blablabla 1</div>
<div class="newClass">blablabla 2</div>
<div class="newClass">blablabla 3</div>
```

Replacing only `<li>` works, with this regex:

```
$pattern = '#<li class="newClass">(.+)</li>#';
$replacement = '<div class="newClass">$1</div>';
$texte = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $texte);
```

I tried to replace the `<ul>` too, but it doesn't work:

```
$pattern = '#<ul>(<li class="myclass">(.+)</li>)*</ul>#';
$replacement = '<div class="newClass">$2</div>';
$texte = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $texte);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform all the `<li>` replacements outside of `<ol>...</ol>` tags with the following regex:

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<skip><ol>.*?<\/ol>))(?&skip)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s*<li\s+class="myclass">(.*?)<\/li>\s*

(?(DEFINE)                  # We set up conditions
   (?<skip><ol>.*?<\/ol>))  # What we skip
   (?&skip)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)   # Fail what we skip
|                           # Else, match this
\s*<li\s+class="myclass">(.*?)<\/li>\s*
```

And replacement string will be:

```
<div class="newClass">$3</div>\n
```

Then, you will just have to remove `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags.

See the [main regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/hE5tV4/7), and the [sample program here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWWxBRUdwNkxJMFk).

```
<?php
   $str = "<ul>\n    <li class=\"myclass\">blablabla 1</li>\n    <li class=\"myclass\">blablabla 2</li>\n    <li class=\"myclass\">blablabla 3</li>\n</ul>\n<ol>\n    <li class=\"myclass\">blablabla 1</li>\n    <li class=\"myclass\">blablabla 2</li>\n    <li class=\"myclass\">blablabla 3</li>\n</ol>\n<ul>\n    <li class=\"myclass\">blablabla 1</li>\n    <li class=\"myclass\">blablabla 2</li>\n    <li class=\"myclass\">blablabla 3</li>\n</ul>"; 
   $re = "/(?(DEFINE)(?<skip><ol>.*?<\\/ol>))(?&skip)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\s*<li\\s+class=\"myclass\">(.*?)<\\/li>\\s*/s"; 
   $subst = "<div class=\"newClass\">$3</div>\n";
   $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
   echo preg_replace("/<\/?ul>/", "", $result);
?>
```

Output:

```
<div class="newClass">blablabla 1</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
<div class="newClass">blablabla 2</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
<div class="newClass">blablabla 3</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                

<ol>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    <li class="myclass">blablabla 1</li>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    <li class="myclass">blablabla 2</li>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    <li class="myclass">blablabla 3</li>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
</ol>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
<div class="newClass">blablabla 1</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
<div class="newClass">blablabla 2</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
<div class="newClass">blablabla 3</div>
```

Comment: @laipreu: Please check my code, it will only replace `<ul>`'s `<li>`s.

Comment: it works thx, but i would like do it in one regex and i don't understand all yours. What is "Define", "<skip>", "*SKIP ", "*FAIL" and "<needle>" ?
Thx !

Comment: I am using Perl-like work around to only capture li tags outside of ol tags. It is not possible to use one regex, as I am replacing with a non-empty string. You may use str_replace to delete ul tags after if you wish.

Comment: I did it, to delete the good ul "preg_replace("#<ul>\s*<div class=\"newClass\">([^\+]*)<\/ul>#", '<div class="newClass">$1', $text)"
Thx all works perfectly !

Comment: Great, just beware of stray `<li>` tags, they will also be affected. Only the `<li>` tags inside `<ol>` will be ignored. I also have  just removed the named capture group, it was not necessary, and added an expanded explanation of the regex.

Comment: Awesome, my regex skills are up. Thx, i can't vote twice, but i would like \m/

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is almost correct.

```
$pattern = '#<ul>(<li class="myclass">(.+)</li>)*</ul>#';
```

Although, there are multiple flaws in your pattern.

- `<ul>` will assume that all your `<li ...` will start with `<ul>` which is not the case for `<li class="myclass">blablabla 2</li>`. So, you have to use it with `?` and preferrably in a non capturing group.. i.e. `(?:<ul>)?` and similarly at the end `(?:<\/ul>)?` (note the **escape character**)
- You are not checking for spaces and newlines before/after `<li..` which should be changed to `(\s*<li class="myclass">(.+)<\/li>\s*)`
- Also, no need to add `*` after `(<li ...>...<\/li>)`

Working modification of your pattern would be `(?:<(?:ul|ol)>)?(\s*<li class="myclass">(.+)<\/li>\s*)(?:<\/(?:ul|ol)>)?`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rK0yE7/1) for more explanation and exploration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanations. It works but if i have another list as :
    <ol><li class="myclass">...</li></ol>

The li are also replaced. There is no way to make this regex only for <li> inside <ul> and not inside <ol> ?

Comment: This regex almost works : (?:<ul>)(\s*<li class="myclass">(.+)<\/li>\s*)*(?:<\/ul>)

But it replaced all my list by one div. I updated the regex page : https://regex101.com/r/rK0yE7/4

Comment: No.. it matches only last capturing group.

Comment: There is no solution to match all the list ? As a "loop", line per line ?

Comment: There is.. but prefix and suffix here will not match per line.. either it is complicated and i have to learn more.. looking into it..

Comment: I'm looking for it. If i find i'll post it. Anyway thx a lot for your help :)